# C++11/14 convert std::uint32 to std::vector<std::uint8>

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I would like to convert `std::uint32` to `std::vector<std::uint8>` in a better way than this:

```
std::uint32_t base_rva = 0xccddee00;
std::vector<std::uint8_t> vraw_data;

//copying base_rva to raw_data
vraw_data.resize(sizeof(base_rva));
std::memcpy(vraw_data.data(), &base_rva, sizeof(base_rva));
```

I was looking for something like:

```
std::vector<std::uint8_t> vraw_data((std::uint8_t*)&base_rva, sizeof(base_rva));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Where the `std::uint32_t` comes in play?

Comment: Sorry about that, I am going to edit the question

Comment: _`v_base_rva.resize(v_base_rva.size() + sizeof(m_base_rva));`_ looks like completely nonsensical and unnecessary code for me, sorry.

Comment: You are right, edited, and looks better now!

Comment: I removed redundant stuff and looks quite better now, any ideas?

Comment: What is the for-loop supposed to accomplish?

Comment: @H.Guijt it is a task specific loop, I am going to remove it because there is nothing to do with my question, thanks for reminding me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was looking for something like:
>
> ```
> std::vector<std::uint8_t> raw_data((std::uint8_t*)&base_rva, sizeof(base_rva));
> ```

There's no such constructor available for `std::vector`, but supposed you want to store the copy of a `std::uint32_t` internal representation in a `std::vector<std::uint8_t>` you can simply do

```
 std::uint32_t data = 42;
 std::vector<std::uint8_t> raw_data( (std::uint8_t*)&data
                                   , (std::uint8_t*)&(data) + sizeof(std::uint32_t));
```

according (4) from [`std::vector` constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector).

Comment: It works! Thank you! The task is all about transforming a std::uint32_t in a way that exactly it looks in memory(liltle endian x86 intel)

Comment: Technically this would break strict aliasing rule if `uint8_t` is not an alias for [unsigned] char.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot very interested on this, can you link me with some information? Isn't std::uint8_t an alias to unsigned char?

Comment: @FranciscoGomes Well, it's unlikely that `std::uint8_t` isn't actually a `typedef uinsigned char uint8_t;` but you might well simply replace `std::uint8_t` with `unsigned char`.

Comment: @FranciscoGomes C++ states that [accessing object through pointer of incompatible type is UB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule). Signed/unsigned and usual `char` pointer is compatible with anything. Fixed width types are not required to alias any specific type: they can in theory be an alias to some compiler intrinsic type (however it is unlikely).

Comment: thanks for reminding me, really valuable information here, thanks!

Comment: Seems the parenthesis don't match? one more close parenthesis in the end?

Comment: also, seems it is no longer (4) in [std::vector constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). but (5).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like casting, you could do it like...

```
union to_byte_vector
{
  uint32_t val;
  uint8_t bytes[1];

  to_byte_vector() = default;
  to_byte_vector(uint32_t v) : val(v) {}
  to_byte_vector(const to_byte_vector& o) : val(o.val) {}
  to_byte_vector& operator=(const to_byte_vector& o) { val = o.val; return *this; }
  operator uint32_t() const { return val; }
  std::vector<uint8_t> get_vector() const { return std::vector<uint8_t>(begin(), end()); }

private:
  const uint8_t* begin() const { return bytes; }
  const uint8_t* end() const { return bytes + sizeof(uint32_t); }
};
```

And use it like...

```
auto vec = to_byte_vector(42).get_vector();
```

But really, this is just letting the `union` do the casting work for you.